# How to create an image-button

Tags: winrt-xaml

I create an image-button using below code:

```
ImageBrush btnBrush1 = new ImageBrush();
 btnBrush1.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

btnBrush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/icon_LogIn.png"));

btnLogIn.Background = btnBrush1;
```

The problem:

1) When using a mouse hovering the img-button, it turn grey background and icon disappear ( when not hovering the img-button, this image button is visible.

I want this image-button visible when hovering it or pressing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Image as Content rather than setting ImageBrush as Background. 
Try this

```
Image img=new Image();
img.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/icon_LogIn.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
btnLogIn.Content = img;
```

Comment: It works using this URI : img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/icon_LogIn.png"));