# Button image background disappears when on hover

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When I create a button with a background and I hover over with my mouse, the background image disappears. Is there a way to override or cancel this process?
I also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321492/how-to-create-an-image-button) that I could set the image as content of the button, however I couldn't get the scaling right (filling the button) programmatically.
Thanks in advance.

How I set the background:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www." + link + ".jpg"));
videoButton.Background = new ImageBrush()
{
   ImageSource = bitmapImage
};
```

Comment: How do you set the background?

Comment: @user2156073 do you have any function on hover ?

Comment: No, I do not have a function on hover.

Comment: Here is the same problem described with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524508/change-button-image-on-hover-or-click

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321492/how-to-create-an-image-button/20324070#20324070

Comment: I referred to that question in my question, however I need the image to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Setter property for button , in fact you need to customize whole button style

```
   <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleName" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the PointerOver visual state for the button overrides the button's background removing your image background.

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
  <Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

One solution is the long way much like unica suggested which is to override the control template for the button and remove the storyboard that changes the background.

The simpler way is to make the button have some content which contains the background. Something along the lines of"

```
videoButton.Content = new Border
{
  Background = new ImageBrush
  {
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www." + link + ".jpg"))
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/myimage.png"));
        Button1.Background = brush;
```

I dont think you set the background properly